# Why is this Xamarin.Android (Mono) C# equals operator (==) override failing in execution but not in Immediate Window?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am having an issue with Xamarin.Android (mono) not evaluating as expected with using the `==` operator overload.

Take the following code:

```
foreach (var sync in Syncs)
{
    if (!sync.HasCompleted &&
        sync.TargetAddress == targetAddress) // == isn't working
    {
        incompleteSyncs.Add(sync); // doesn't get hit
    }

    if (!sync.HasCompleted &&
        sync.TargetAddress.Equals(targetAddress)) // works
    {
        incompleteSyncs.Add(sync); // get's hit
    }
}
```

In the immediate window, using the `==` works correctly (i.e. evaluates to `true` in my case). By this, I mean I simply copy and paste the exact code in the Immediate window here and it evaluates to `true`. During execution of the actual Xamarin.Android app, it does not (i.e. `false`).

Here is the code for the == override:

```
public static bool operator ==(ibPorpAddress a, ibPorpAddress b)
{
    // If both are null, or both are same instance, return true.
    if (System.Object.ReferenceEquals(a, b))
    {
        return true;
    }

    // If one is null, but not both, return false.
    if (((object)a == null) || ((object)b == null))
    {
        return false;
    }

    // Return true if the fields match:
    return a.Equals(b);
}
```

It seems like this override is being ignored by Mono during execution, but not in the Immediate window. When I set a breakpoint in this overload, it is not hit. However, the breakpoint in my `Equals` method is hit when I use the `.Equals(..)` call directly.

In the Immediate window, I also checked GetHashCode for giggles and they are also the same for both addresses.

What da dilly?

Comment: Probably this has got nothing to do with your problem, but where you say _"If one is null, but not both, return false."_ shouldn't you be using the ^ operator? : `if (((object)a == null) ^ ((object)b == null))` ..

Comment: Ah thats just template code from MS snippet. The ^ is probably better so good spot. I'll probably change that snippet, but I think you're right about not being the problem lol!

Comment: Although I wonder if ReferenceEquals(null, null) returns true. In which case it would be an unnecessary change.

Comment: You're right.._ReferenceEquals_ already takes account of both references being null :)

Comment: Ah it's there in MS snippet comments! hah `// If both are null, or both are same instance, return true.` Thanks for the comments though! :-O

Comment: First, the operator is _overloaded_, not _overridden_. Second, if you get different results in runtime as in the immediate window, then at least one of those scenarios is not using the operator overload. Why this would be, depends entirely on the exact context, but without a good [mcve] there's no way to know what that context is.

Comment: First, regarding overload vs overridden: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms173147(v=vs.80).aspx. I can understand your point, but you should argue with MS not me (and your comment is phrased argumentatively btw). Second, the MCV is a philosophical decision and one that I do not agree with. What you are essentially saying is that I do not have enough information for **you** to come up with the answer. So instead of wasting my time (and doing it in a condescending manner), just don't answer. A person with expert knowledge of Mono and Immediate Window internals could possibly answer.

Comment: And who is voting to close this and why?

Comment: And btw, I've read and reread Jon Skeet's epic "Writing the perfect question" at http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/, and I spent time distilling this advanced problem down to the bare minimal facts, following that guideline as best I can. I'd appreciate any comments to be invested as well, instead of soap box rhetoric.